# Getting platform browser error after upgrading to Ionic 5 from Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

ERROR:

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.d.ts(15,10): error TS2305: Module '"node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler"' has no exported member 'JitEvaluator'.

Below is my package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk-experimental": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/admob-plus": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/ng-toolkit": "^1.1.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/schematics-angular": "^1.0.7",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "0.22.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "0.25.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "^5.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^6.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.8.6",
    "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.4.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.21",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "00000000000",
        "APP_NAME": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.40.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-admob-sdk": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "16.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {
        "ADMOB_APP_ID": "ca-app-pub-0000000000000000"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": {},
      "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "16+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {
        "CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
        "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
        "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "19.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "18.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "18.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "18.0.0",
        "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "2.10.1",
        "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "2.1.0",
        "ANDROID_SHORTCUTBADGER_VERSION": "1.1.22"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "16.0.1"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using npm-check-update (ncu). It is here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

It will non-destructively check your project's dependencies and tell you which ones can be updated. Then you can run it in update mode, and it will update your package.json. Then you run npm update to actually update the packages.

It helped me out of a big jam once when I got into version hell due to trying to run an ionic project that was developed on a pc, on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still here, what fixed it for me was updating my @angular/compiler to 9.1.13 as that was the version compatible with my angular version. Just do a fresh `npm install` after deleting node_modules and it should work fine.